# How to share files

Tags: support

If I am to share a file what's the appropriate way?

See [my answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/80815/13649) for context.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange has good support for images and videos, through Imgur and YouTube. For all others, just host them wherever you like and post a link.